# radio button selecionado de acordo com BD no foreach

Tags: php, foreach, radiobutton

Bom dia, como posso fazer para deixar o radiobutton selecionado de acordo com o banco de dados, tenho uma tabela no banco com as categorias sendo listadas em um foreach no radiobutton, ate ai beleza, funciona pra inserir, mas na hora de editar eu preciso que um radiobutton esteja selecionado de acordo com o id que esta na tabela produtos relacionado ao campo de id da tabela de categorias, e nessa parte não estou conseguindo fazer, meu código abaixo:

```
<?php
        foreach($listar_categorias as $categoria):
        if($categoria['id'] == $campos['categoria']){ $check = 'checked';}
?>
        <input type="radio" name ="cat_select" value="<?php $categoria['id']; ?>" checked="<?php echo $check; ?>" required="require" /><p><?php echo $categoria['nome']; ?></p>
<?php   
        endforeach;
?>
```

da forma como esta a ultima opção do banco tal como nos radiobuttons fica selecionada.

Comment: Com este código o que acontece? Da algum erro? Algum `radiobutton` aparece marcado?

Comment: aparece o ultimo radiobutton marcado, em todos, uma vez q e pra aparecer marcado na opcao denominada no banco

Comment: Imaginava que era isso mesmo, postei uma resposta.

Comment: muito obg deu certo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que a variável `$check` não esta sendo limpa antes da verificação. Dessa forma todos os itens após o que realmente deveria estar selecionado também estarão com `checked="checked"`. Como a propriedade `name` é igual, o ultimo com a propriedade `checked="checked"` sempre estará marcado.

A solução é limpar a variável `check`:

```
<?php
    foreach($listar_categorias as $categoria):
        $check = '';
        if($categoria['id'] == $campos['categoria']){
            $check = 'checked="checked"';
        }
?>
    <input type="radio" name ="cat_select" value="<?php $categoria['id']; ?>" <?php echo $check; ?> required="require" /><p><?php echo $categoria['nome']; ?></p>
<?php   
    endforeach;
?>
```

Repare que eu troquei o conteúdo da variável `$check` de `checked` para `checked="checked"`, isso porque se o item não deve estar marcado, nem precisa declarar a propriedade `checked`.